# Jinja2 - Output key:value format from nested dictionary

Tags: jinja2

I have a dictionary like so:

```
name: baggagescreen
favorite:
  color: red
  car:
    make: hyundai
    model: sonata
    color: green
    year: 1998
```

The contents may vary, the depths may vary. But I need to render it like this (all on one line):

```
name:baggagescreen, favorite.color:red, favorite.car.make:hyundai, favorite.car.model:sonata, favorite.car.color:green, favorite.car.year:1998
```

I have perused some snippets using "recursive" and "loop", but anything I've come up with is either super inelegant or can't handle arbitrary recursive depths. Since I need the whole key (favorite.car.make) printed instead of just the last one (make) the examples I've encountered don't cut it.

Is this possible in Jinja without some reaaaaally nasty code?